# BLRAAZ hexadecimal value

Tags: assembly, arm, hex, arm64

As said in the title, does anyone know the hexadecimal of the `BLRAAZ` instruction (like `blraaz x19`) ?

It seems to be not implemented yet in `radare2` and I can't find any values on internet.

Comment: Use a different assembler; GNU binutils and clang both recognize it as a valid mnemonic so you should be able to assemble it to machine code in an object file with them; from there you can hexdump it (e.g. with `objdump`).  Although clang says "instruction requires: pa" and I don't know how to enable that CPU feature...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acording to the [ARM a64 instruction set architecture](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0596/a/DDI_0596_ARM_a64_instruction_set_architecture.pdf) (page 98), the instruction `BLRAAZ <Xn>` is

```
+---------------+-----+---------------------------+-------+------------+----------+
| 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 | Z=0 | 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 | M = 0 | Rn = ????? | Rm=11111 |
+---------------+-----+---------------------------+-------+------------+----------+
```

in binary notation i.e. `0xD63F081F` in hexadecimal. `Rn` is your register number here. For `x19`, just set `Rn=10011` here and you got `0xD63F0A7F`.

Comment: Many thanks! So if I follow the logic for `x20` it would be `0xD63F0A80` and `x21` it would be `0xD63F0AA0` ?

Comment: so it was easy to find on the internet then?

Comment: @TsunaSawada Not quite, the register number is stored in bits 5 to 10 of the instruction, i.e. 5 bits shifted to the left (as a formula `0xD63F081F or (Rn << 5)`). Accordingly `BLRAAZ x20` would be `0xD63F0A9F` and so on.
@old_timer The difficulty here is probably to read the notation in the document. Google delivers [this document](http://shell-storm.org/armv8-a/ISA_v85A_A64_xml_00bet8/xhtml/blra.html) too, in my case the third hit.

Answer (score 1):

Even faster than looking online for the answer you could just try it:

```
blraaz x19
```

assemble then disassemble

```
   0:   d63f0a7f    blraaz  x19
```

EDIT:

going backward (with binutils)

```
.inst 0xd63f0a7f

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   d63f0a7f    blraaz  x19


aarch64-none-elf-as --version
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.34
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `aarch64-none-elf'.

apt-get install binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu

aarch64-linux-gnu-as --version
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.30
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `aarch64-linux-gnu'.

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   d63f0a7f    blraaz  x19


blraaz x19


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   d63f0a7f    blraaz  x19
```

so the apt-gettable 2.30 also supports this instruction.  (vs building 2.34 from sources)

Comment: What toolchain are you using?  I thought it was going to be this easy, but `clang -target aarch64` won't assemble that in a file by itself.  It says `error: instruction requires: pa`.  And with GNU `aarch64-linux-gnu-as` (2.34), I get ```Error: selected processor does not support `blraaz x19'```.  Also, using `.word` to put the bytes in a file and disassemble just shows it as `.word 0xd63f0a7f` not by the mnemonic (again, up-to-date cross-binutils or llvm-objdump on x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux).

Comment: I used binutils

Comment: read the error message you get back "selected processor does not support `blraaz x19'" so then since there isnt yet a processor with that you select the architecture

Comment: a while ago they made it so .word doesnt necessarily work so use .inst instead

Comment: @PeterCordes  I only have two flavors of cortex-m and an armv4t clang/llvm so cant test this without that research project.  The time it took to ask the question they could have found the answer.  The OP clearly didnt put any effort into looking on the internet.  We really shouldnt be spending any time on this question and just close it.

Comment: I had to use `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -march=armv8.3-a -c foo.s` or higher to get it to assemble.  I was surprised that the assembler was doing ISA-version checking by default, with no `-march` or `-mcpu` options.  GAS for x86-64 doesn't do that; by default it allows everything unless you set a specific CPU or group of extensions to enforce.  And yeah, `.inst` worked for manual assembly.

Comment: gcc is a C compiler and not part of binutils.  this is assembly language.  every target is different even if under the gnu umbrella, different authors, different features, different language nuances (outside "instructions").  The tool is built with a default which you can control then beyond that you use -mcpu which then triggers arch and fpu and such, or you pick those separately....for arm....wait until you see risc-v and other similar (nightmare) architectures, they go way beyond arm (or x86, etc).

Comment: interestingly or not the disassembler, tries to dissassemble whatever it sees independent of the selected architecture/cpu

Comment: yes armv8.3-a is the key, what was disturbing is that 1 arm changed their website and it is not as good IMO, but still gets you to the info.  but 2) they only appear to offer armv8 in the ARM ARM rather than their tradition of adding the new instructions in and in the description for the instruction stating the architecture that supports that instruction (and/or which dont).  So these 8.x instructions you have to come to through a different path (using the search button) rather than front door download the ARM ARM for that architecture.

Comment: so maybe when they sell an 8.x core to someone we might then see a complete arm arm...or maybe I wasnt patient enough in what I was wading through.  so instead if finding the encoding being just a couple of minutes of clicking and downloading, it was a little bit longer than that.

Comment: Calm down, I just used the gcc front-end to invoke `aarch64-linux-gnu-as` with arch options in whatever form it wants them!  It turns out `-march=armv8.3-a` would have worked as an option to `aarch64-linux-gnu-as` directly, but I didn't know that.  I happen to know that the `gcc` front-end command invokes `cc1`, `as`, and/or `ld` depending on the extension(s) of the file(s) you put on its command line.